# Filtering in Telerik RadGird not working

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am developing a page with telerik RadGrid and the filtering feature is not working. I enable the filtering at grid an table level but it just execute the rebind action without filtering.

To fill the table I am using the NeedDataSource mode. What I am not sure is if the data stay attached to the GridItem and if that could be the problem.

This is the event that just get the DataSource from a service connecting to a DAO:

```
protected void MaterialsGrid_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e) 
{ 
    MaterialsGrid.DataSource = orderService.GetSalesOrderItemsBySector(SessionService.CurrentSectors); 
}
```

I am also using a Template column with particular behaeviour but I am not enableing filter on this column.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with the Telerik RadGrid before and it turned out to be due to disabled viewstate. You may also examine the online demos of the grid on the Telerik's site under the Filtering category and the FilterTemplate sample (fifth from top to bottom).

Dick

Answer (score 2):

set the `datafield ="column name"` for the template column then it will work fine.